# How to get the initial address of the heap?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, heap-memory

I'm working on a implementation of malloc using `sbrk()`

If want to get the initial address of the heap do i just call `sbrk(0)` and set a pointer to it?

Comment: According to the [`sbrk` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) it returns the *current* location of the break if you pass a zero. So it will only return the initial heap address if (and only if) you never called it with a non-zero argument before for the current process.

Comment: Yes. Although the modern approach to obtaining memory directly from the kernel is to `mmap` /dev/zero.

Answer (score 0):

When building `malloc()`, you get your heap blocks by calling `sbrk(n)` where `n` is the size of each heap block (which must be at least as large as the memory you are currently allocating + room for headers).

While `sbrk(0)` does indeed return the start of the heap the first time its called, blocks from `sbrk()` need not be contiguous (hint: there ain't no rule the application can't call `sbrk()` itself, but also `mmap()` allocates from the same address space) so calling `sbrk(0)` and stretching the heap continuously upwards will not work.